# Give the copy a specific name, sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How can I give a copy of one of my spreadsheets a specific name. Like giving them a week number.

This is what I have so far:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("***********"); 

    DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy("Copy", destFolder);
```

So how can I add a number (from the sheet preferably) to the new file name "copy"?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here it is:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("*********"); 
  var weekNumber = sheet.getRange("E1");
  var week = [weekNummer1.getCell(1, 1).getValue()];
    DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy("Copy"+ (week), destFolder);
```